# How can I redirect users from a url to another using regex and htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect users from `www.example.com/ANYTHING` to `www.example.com`.

Is `.htaccess` the better way to do it? How can I do it?

Comment: You want to redirect **ALL** requests back to the home page or to the same path on a different domain?

Answer (score 0):

If you really just have to remove everything after `www.mydomain.com`, then you just have to delete everything from the first `/` to the end of the URL:

Search for this regex

```
%^([^/]*).*$
```

and substitute with `\1`, as I did [here](https://regex101.com/r/DwbhaP/1). Note that I have used the `%` sign as delimiter instead of `/`, so I don't need to escape the `/` in the regex. (I could have used any other available symbol other than `/`.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` (as opposed to a mod-alias `RedirectMatch`) in order to avoid conflicts with mod_dir and the `DirectoryIndex`<sup>***1**</sup>.

For example, in `.htaccess` (Apache 2.2 and 2.4):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule . / [R,L]
```

The single dot matches *something* (ie. not the document root) and we redirect to the document root.

However, if the document root is an HTML webpage that links to resources like JavaScript, CSS and images then you need to make exceptions for these resources, otherwise these too will be redirected to the root!

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|jpg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . / [R,L]
```

---

<sup>***1**</sup> A mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive such as `RedirectMatch /. /` ends up matching the rewritten request (by mod_dir) to the `DirectoryIndex` (eg. `index.php`) resulting in a redirect loop.